# SharePoint Server Throws exception when doing a long operation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services, sharepoint-addin, multithreading

I have a SharePoint application with SP server 2010 installed, everything is working well, but there is a special method which is performed in 12 - 14 minutes. What's done in this method is that i'm requesting a web service to fetch all data (big amount). So what i did is a Thread.sleep(5000), every 5 seconds i check for response.

The problem, is after exactly 10 minutes, i have exception thrown

```
Category : Error
Level    : Unexpected
Message  : - Message : message additionnel : Configuration problem to access Si
       mulWebservice exception : Thread was being aborted. - Stack Trace : 
         at System.Threading.Thread.SleepInternal(Int32 millisecondsTimeout
       )     at Tegaz.Simul.Web.SPSSiLog.Services.SimulServiceRequest.GetBa
       lancing(Int32 simuId, Int32 userId)



 Category : Error
Level    : Unexpected
Message  : - Message : message additionnel : Error during run balancing button 
           click exception : Thread was being aborted. - Stack Trace :   at Services.SimulServiceRequest.GetBalancing(Int32 simuId, Int32 userId)     at Services.SimulServiceRequest.GetAndOptimBalancing(BalancingFetchingParam fetchingParam, Int32 userId)    at WebParts.Simul
           ZoneVisualWebPart.SimulZoneVisualWebPartUserControl.RunBalancingClic
           k(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

At first, i was thinking that it was a problem linked to the web.config or app.config timeout value (but this value is set at 59 minutes).
Then i thought that may be it comes from idle Timeout in the web site app pool, but the Value was set correctly (at 0).
Right now, i have absolutely no idea, what is the reason of this problem. This is very weird, because i'm barely sure that is a configuration problem linked to the IIS server.

Your suggestions are welcome.
Best regards.

Comment: How are your Resource throttling settings configured? Go to Central Administration > Manage Web Applications > Select the web application > General Settings > Resource Throttling. Also visit http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg491393.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not change nothing.

Comment: May be, instead of Thread.Sleep(), i will try the ASP.net auto refresh function, may be that will solve the problem

Comment: You mentioned asp.net auto refresh... is this operation executed from a web page (for example after an user clicks a button or something)? Any way you could refactor the current code to an asynch call to the web service? I suspect that the Thread.Sleep method is the responsible. For a simple test, comment out the call to the web service and just substitute it with a long cycle (200 iteration) that sleeps 5s/cycle. That should at least verify if the problem is related to the service call.

Comment: Also, check if the Task Manager/Resource Viewer/other shows any sign of a memory usage growth... maybe there is an OutOfMemory error hiding somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, this operation is executed on a web page after a button click